# How to split data into groups in pyspark

Tags: sql, select, pyspark, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need to find groups in time series data.

Data sample

[image]

I need to output column `group` based on `value` and `day`.

I've tried using lag, lead and row_number but it ended up to nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`PySpark`** *way to do this*. Find endpoints of groups using **`lag`**, do an **`incremental sum`** on this **`lag`** to get **`groups`**, **`add 1`** to groups to get your **`desired groups.`**

```
from pypsark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w1=Window().orderBy("day")
df.withColumn("lag", F.when(F.lag("value").over(w1)!=F.col("value"), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
  .withColumn("group", F.sum("lag").over(w1) + 1).drop("lag").show()

#+-----+---+-----+
#|value|day|group|
#+-----+---+-----+
#|    1|  1|    1|
#|    1|  2|    1|
#|    1|  3|    1|
#|    1|  4|    1|
#|    1|  5|    1|
#|    2|  6|    2|
#|    2|  7|    2|
#|    1|  8|    3|
#|    1|  9|    3|
#|    1| 10|    3|
#|    1| 11|    3|
#|    1| 12|    3|
#|    1| 13|    3|
#+-----+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you want to increment the group everytime the value changes. If so, this is a kind of gaps-and-islands problem.

Here is one approach that uses `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()`:

```
select
    value,
    day,
    sum(case when value = lag_value then 0 else 1 end) over(order by day) grp
from (
    select t.*, lag(value) over(order by day) lag_value
    from mytable t
) t
```